CREAR INTERFACES PROPIAS EN SPRING BOOT
en mi aplicacion API-rest para mandar BOEs a usuarios estoy intentando crear una clase que implemente métodos propios para luego extenderlos a través de una interfaz junto a la de JPA:
public interface IBoeUser extends JpaRepository<BoeUser, Long>, ICustomRepository{

    @Query("SELECT bu.boe FROM BoeUser bu WHERE bu.user.id = :userId")
    List<Boe> findBoesByUserId(Long userId);

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Boe b WHERE b NOT IN (SELECT bu.boe FROM BoeUser bu WHERE bu.user.id = :userId)")
    List<Boe> findNotReceivedBoesByUserId(Long userId);



    List<BoeUser> findByBoe(Boe ultimoBoe);



}


public interface ICustomRepository{

     List<Boe> customNoRecibidos(Long userId);


}

@Repository
public class CustomRepository implements ICustomRepository {



    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Override
    public List<Boe> customNoRecibidos(Long userId) {




        System.out.println("Test de uso del metodo custom");
        String hql = "SELECT b FROM Boe b " +
                "WHERE b NOT IN " +
                "(SELECT bu.boe FROM BoeUser bu " +
                "WHERE bu.user.id = :userId)";
        TypedQuery<Boe> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Boe.class);
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}


Obtengo un error al que no encuentro mucho sentido:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'customNoRecibidos' found for type 'BoeUser'

No se si tengo mal la estructura (me la han pedido asi) o a que se debe.

Si etiquetaste una clase con @Repository debes haber utilizado @autowired para instanciar esa clase, ya que con @Repository estas etiquetando esa clase para que solo se pueda instanciar mediante el runtime de Spring. Lo mismo sería para la clase BoeUser que no pones pero que supongo que tiene el mismo problema porque el error dice que el runtime de spring no encontró la propiedad customNoRecibidos de la clase BoeUser.

La clase BoeUser la tengo como entidad:
Entity
Table(name = "boe_user")
public class BoeUser {
@Id
GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
ManyToOne
JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

ManyToOne
JoinColumn(name = "boe_id")
private Boe boe;
private Long customNoRecibidos;
private static  List<User> suscritos;
public BoeUser (){
    this.suscritos=null; }

Me ha tocado poner "private Long customNoRecibidos;" para que deje de saltar el error.  ¿Donde deberia hacer autowired?
